# how do i pass python object as argument to C# program

Tags: c#, python, .net, object, parameter-passing

I have a C# windows application, where i need to pass object created in python script - as argument to C# program and vice-verse. 
    **So how do i pass object created by Python script to C# program as parameter.**

For this, i **don't want to use Iron-Python**. My strict requirement is to use object created by running the **C Python** scripts. My Python script reads a json file and creates object.

My sample Json string :

```
{"?xml":{"@version":"1.0","@encoding":"Windows-1252"},"TestScript":{"TestExperiment":{"Test1":{"Control":[{"@Type":"System.Windows.Forms.TextBox","@Name":"Description","@FormName":"Test1","Text":null,"Visible":"True"},{"@Type":"System.Windows.Forms.TextBox","@Name":"Objective","@FormName":"Test1","Text":null,"Visible":"True"},{"@Type":"System.Windows.Forms.TextBox","@Name":"Test1","@FormName":"Test1","Text":null,"Visible":"True"}]}}}}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If your python objects are serialized as Json, I think you should first use the Json.net package to parse the input strings as Json Objects.

For instance:

```
JObject obj = Jobject.Parse(jsonString);
```

After that, I would recommened you create C# objects that mirror your python objects and then deserialize them into real objects.

For instance:

```
// Json String to Object
Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(productJsonString);
```

Comment: i trying to deserialize the Jsonstring to C# object but it returns null. I need to mark c# classes as serializable ??

Comment: i have pasted my sample json string

Comment: Use JToken.Parse() if it a complex object like this one.

Comment: Also, if DeserializeObject<T> doesn't work, this means that you haven't written your C# class correctly.